# Reduce function shows NaN or Undefined when used along with map() function in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to get the total from objects (product, sellingPrice) that renders dynamically on the screen after they have been entered through a form. I am using the map() function to loop through the list of entered data and using the reduce() function to get the sum total and display them on the screen, I think I am having issues with the reduce function as it shows NaN and Undefined in the console: I will gladly appreciate your help, thanks. Here are the useStates.

````
const [productName, setProductName] = useState("");
const [sellingPrice, setSellingPrice] = useState(0);
const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([])```
//Here is then code

const displayAddedItemList = () => {
    if (!visible) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Items</div>
                {newItems.map((items)=>{
                    const {productName,sellingPrice} = items;
                    return(
                        <>
                        <div className='itemsAdded'>
                            <div className='eachItemAdded'>  
                                <div>{productName}</div>
                                <div>{sellingPrice}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='deleteEditFont'> 
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </>
                        );
                    }).reduce(function(a,b) {
                        return 
                            <div className='totalItemsAdded'>
                                <p>Total</p>
                                <p>${a + b.sellingPrice}</p>
                            </div>;
                    }) 
                }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
````

Comment: `var a = [<div>xyz</div>,<div>abc</div>];  a.reduce(.....`   <--  doing that makes no sense.   You need to use `newItems.reduce(` on another line..

Answer (score 1):

### the problem is

that the reduce function was placed inside the map function, which resulted in unexpected behavior. When you used return within the reduce function, it caused the map function to return undefined, and that's why you were getting NaN or undefined.

```
const displayAddedItemList = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>Items</div>
          {visible &&
            newItems.map((item) => (
              <div key={item.productName} className='itemsAdded'>
                <div className='eachItemAdded'>
                  <div>{item.productName}</div>
                  <div>{item.sellingPrice}</div>
                </div>
                <div className='deleteEditFont'>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} />
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          {visible && (
            <div className='totalItemsAdded'>
              <p>Total</p>
              <p>${newItems.reduce((total, item) => total + item.sellingPrice, 0)}</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer it saved a whole lot of time but rather than having the sum of all "selling price", its kindoff joining them together, say we have selling price of 20 and 40 we see something like 2040 instead of actual sum which is 60

Comment: I just figured it out, the joining is as a result of the fact that `item.sellingPrice` is a string not a number hence its concating all totals instead of adding it up. so what i did was to do this `parseFloat(item.sellingPrice)` converting it to a number. thanks once again.